# android sharingIntent for different actions

Tags: android, android-intent, share

For the following shareIntent:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);         
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "to share this!"));
```

The app will then pop up list of app that have sharing function:

I would like to ask if it is possible to code in a way that if the customer choose eg. whatsapp or SMS it will do Action A, yet if customer choose Facebook it will do Action B?

Thanks!

Comment: I bet you can use `IntentFilter` to filter out the matching intent, and get back a list of packages, then you can create your own dialog for the packages, and do whatever you want when user select one of the applications.

Comment: let me research for some examples and revert to you =) thanks!!

Comment: Let me know if you need help

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is something like using `startActivityForResult()` and hope that the target application will set the result so you can receive a meaningful `Intent data` in `onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){}
```

However; unfortunately this is **not** reliable and does not work with most of the apps.

I have tested it with multiple apps including SMS, Google+, Facebook, Gmail and ColorNote; and for all of them I am getting `data=nulll` in my `onActivityResult` except for `ColorNote` which I am getting a valid `Intent data` with action like `content://note.socialnmobile.provider.colornote/notes/41`

So it really depends on the target application and there is no other reliable method I am aware of that allow your app to know which application the user selected to share the data.

Comment: yes =) i have tried this one also before for posting a image to facebook and out of my expectation it works successfully...but really it is not reliable

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example of option of sharing I did awhile ago

**UPDATE:**

```
public class CustomShareDialogActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList< AppToSendOption > appsOptions = new ArrayList< AppToSendOption >();

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle arg0 ) {
    super.onCreate( arg0 );
    setContentView( R.layout.show_share_dialog );
    final Button button = (Button)findViewById( R.id.button1 );
    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick( View v ) {
            getListOfShareApps();
            showShareDialog();              
        }
    } );

}

private void getListOfShareApps() {
    if( !appsOptions.isEmpty() ){ return; }

    Intent sendOption = new Intent();
    sendOption.setType( "application/*" );
    sendOption.setAction( Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE );
    List< ResolveInfo > ris = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( sendOption, 0 );

    for ( ResolveInfo ri : ris ) {
        Drawable icon = ri.loadIcon( getPackageManager() );
        String appname = ( String ) ri.loadLabel( getPackageManager() );
        String packagename = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        String classname = ri.activityInfo.name;
        appsOptions.add( new AppToSendOption( icon, appname, packagename, classname ) );
    }
}

private void showShareDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
    ArrayAdapter< AppToSendOption > adapter01 = new SendOptionsAdapter( this, appsOptions );
    builder.setTitle( "Options" )
            .setSingleChoiceItems( adapter01, -1, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
            AppToSendOption app = appsOptions.get( which );
            String packagename = app.getPackagename();
            String classname = app.getClassname();
            // Right here, check the package name to see which app is selected, and do the appropriate
            // action.
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), packagename + ", " + classname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    } ).setNegativeButton( "Cancel", null ).show();

}

private class AppToSendOption {

    Drawable icon;
    String appname;
    String packagename;
    String classname;

    public AppToSendOption( Drawable icon, String appname, String packagename, String classname ) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.appname = appname;
        this.packagename = packagename;
        this.classname = classname;
    }

    Drawable getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    String getAppname() {
        return appname;
    }

    String getPackagename() {
        return packagename;
    }

    String getClassname() {
        return classname;
    }
}

public class SendOptionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter< AppToSendOption > {
    private List< AppToSendOption > apps;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private static final int RESOURCE = R.layout.send_option_dialog;

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
    }

    public SendOptionsAdapter( Context context, List< AppToSendOption > objects ) {
        super( context, RESOURCE, objects );
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        apps = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate( RESOURCE, null );
            holder.text = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.textView_appname );
            holder.text.setTextColor( Color.BLACK );
            holder.icon = ( ImageView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.imageView_appicon );
            holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds( true );
            holder.icon.setScaleType( ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE );
            convertView.setTag( holder );
        } else {
            holder = ( ViewHolder ) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable( apps.get( position ).getIcon() );
        holder.text.setText( apps.get( position ).getAppname() );

        return convertView;
    }
}


}
```

And here is the xml file of send_option_dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_appicon"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_appname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>
```

**It is not perfect, you might consider using DialogFragment instead, but hopefully this will give you the idea how to create the dialog.**

Comment: could you please kindly also tell me how to create AlertDialog together with the ArrayList? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ask if it is possible to code in a way that if the customer choose eg. whatsapp or SMS it will do Action A, yet if customer choose Facebook it will do Action B?

No, for two reasons:

1. An `Intent` has only one action, and `startActivity()` (and `createChooser()`) take only one `Intent`.
2. There is no "whatsapp". There is no "SMS". There is no "Facebook". There are apps, with varying package names, and you have no way of reliably determining whether a particular package name is "whatsapp" or "SMS" or "Facebook". For example, there are hundreds, if not thousands, of SMS clients.

If you want to allow the user to share multiple types of things (e.g., short strings or long strings), give the user a choice of what to share. If the user wishes to use a short string with Facebook instead of a longer string, that is the *user's* decision to make, not yours.

Comment: oh you are correct! then could it be except for packagename.contains(facebook) then do Action B, else for remaining choices all do Action A?

Comment: @pearmak: I could publish an app with `facebook` in the package name whenever I wanted. Moreover, as I stated, *it is not your decision* as to what the user sends to a particular app. Give the user a range of things to share, and allow the user to share those things where the user wants, when the user wants, how the user wants.

Comment: @pearmak Just so you know, you could try and find out facebook's package name and find out if its installed specifically.